# Pass comma-separated list as string of numbers to query as list of integers for PostgreSQL db in C# using Npgsql

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, parameter-passing, npgsql

In my WinForms project written in C# I'm connecting to a PostgreSQL database using the Npgsql framework.

I'm populating a couple of DGVs with a DataTable from the PG database. I'm also trying to implement a search feature that, when initiated by the user, searches the DGV's DataTable for the search string and then rebuilds the DGV based on those results. As the process searches the DataTable, it's building a list of record IDs (ex, "1234,2345,3456") that will be passed to the db query to repopulate the DGV with just the records that match the user's search value.

Here's my search function that builds the list of IDs and the db query:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = txtSearchCatsGrid.Text;
    string idToAddToList = "";
    string tempIdList = "";
    string idListForQuery = "";

    DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dgvCategories.DataSource);
    string cellValue;
    int rowIndex;
    int columnIndex;

    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; columnIndex++)
        {
            cellValue = dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex].ToString();

            if (searchText == cellValue)
            {
                // Set corresponding dgvCategories cell's background color to yellow
                dgvCategories[columnIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                idToAddToList = dt.Rows[rowIndex][0].ToString();
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idToAddToList) && !tempIdList.Contains(idToAddToList)) tempIdList += idToAddToList + ",";

    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempIdList))
    {
        // Remove the trailing comma that was added the last time an id was added to the list
        idListForQuery = tempIdList.Remove(tempIdList.Length - 1, 1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("idListForQuery: " + idListForQuery);

    // Refresh dgvCategories with just rows from search, using idListForQuery

    string companyFilter = cboSelectCompany.Text;
    string categoryFilter = cboSelectCategory.Text;

    db categoriesData = new db();

    if (categoryFilter == "All Categories")
    {
        string catsQuery = "SELECT id, category, source_company, old_value, old_desc, new_value, new_desc, reference1, reference2 " +
                            "FROM masterfiles.xref"+
                            " WHERE company_name = @company" +
                                " AND id IN (@idList)" +
                                //" AND id IN (SELECT UNNEST(@idList))" +
                            " ORDER BY category, old_value, source_company";
        this.dtCategories = categoriesData.GetDgvData(catsQuery, companyFilter, categoryFilter, idListForQuery);
    }
    else
    {
        string catsQuery = "SELECT id, category, source_company, old_value, old_desc, new_value, new_desc, reference1, reference2 " +
                            "FROM masterfiles.xref" +
                            " WHERE company_name = @company" +
                                " AND category = @category" +
                                " AND id IN (@idList)" +
                                //" AND id IN (SELECT UNNEST(@idList))" +
                            " ORDER BY old_value, source_company";
        this.dtCategories = categoriesData.GetDgvData(catsQuery, companyFilter, categoryFilter, idListForQuery);
    }

    dgvCategories.DataSource = this.dtCategories;

    if (dtCategories.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        dgvCategories.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dgvCategories.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Then in my db class, the GetDgvData() function looks like this:

```
public DataTable GetDgvData(string selectQuery, string companyFilter, string categoryFilter, string idFilter)
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("company", companyFilter));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idFilter)) cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("idList", idFilter);
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idFilter)) cmd.Parameters.Add("idList", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = idFilter;
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idFilter)) cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("idList", "ARRAY[" + idFilter + "]"));

        if (categoryFilter != "All Categories") cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("category", categoryFilter));

        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble with using that list of IDs as a parameter in the query.

You'll notice that I have several lines commented out in both code blocks. Those are various attempts at passing the list, all of which generate an error at the line `da.Fill(ds);`

When I just use the uncommented line in the query building code, `AND id IN (@idList)` and the "regular" method of adding a parameter, `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idFilter)) cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("idList", idFilter);`, also ucommented in the `GetDgvData()` function, the error at `da.Fill(ds);` is an NpgsqlPostgresException, "operator does not exist: integer = text'".

After some research I tried the `UNNEST()` function in the query code and left the parameter code. When I try that, I get an Exception saying that function doesn't exist.

After some more research, I found a code example that casts the Array db type to an Integer db Type, which is the first line of commented code in the parameters section in the `GetDgvData()` function. When I tried that, the Exception thrown was, "System.InvalidCastException: 'Can't write type System.String as an array of System.Int32'".

After yet more research, I tried the third commented line in the `GetDgvData()` function, that surrounds the parameter with `"Array[]"`. The Exception I get for that is, "operator does not exist: integer = text'". I tried that with and without the `UNNEST()` function in the query. Without `UNNEST()` I get a Npgsql.PostgresException, "operator does not exist: integer = text'". Using `UNNEST()` I get the PostgresException, "function unnest(text) does not exist'".

I also built the ids as a `List<>` and tried passing it to `GetDgvData()` but I'm not passing it correctly or something because I'm getting a null reference exception in `GetDgvData()` when it gets to the line where I try to do something with the `List<>` - including just trying to look at the contents in the Console.

So I really don't know what else to try from here.

Others have successfully used the above code in their respective solutions, so I can only assume I'm missing something, but what it could be, I have NO idea.

Comment: Have you tried converting the `idList` string to an `int[]` first? `int[] ids = idList.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();`

Comment: @RufusL,forgive my ignorance (I'm on a crash course learning this stuff for this project!), but I tried plugging your example in before the query string is built, then passed that to `GetDgvData`() (changing the idFilter type to `int[]`), but when I ran it, at `ds.Fill(da]` I got an exception, "operator does not exist: integer = integer[]'".

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to deconstruct, so I'm going to attempt to boil this down to just what I think is wrong.  I am hopeful it is enough to get you on track.

It looks like you attempted to use an array, which is absolutely the way to go.  The problem is you used `IN` which is for discrete lists.  For an array you need to use `ANY`.

```
select *
from foo
where bar in (1, 2, 3)
```

translates to

```
select *
from foo
where bar = any (array[1, 2, 3]) -- or shorthand any ('{1,2,3}')
```

Secondly, unless you use dynamic SQL, if you call a bind variable, you need to assign a value to it.  The converse is not true.  So, once you declare `@category` in your SQL, you MUST assign it a value in C#.  One possible way around this is to wrap your C# logic within the SQL -- I don't believe you will experience any performance hit for this.

Your revised query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  id, category, source_company, old_value, old_desc, new_value, new_desc, 
  reference1, reference2 
FROM masterfiles.xref
WHERE
  company_name = @company
  AND (category = @category or @category = 'All Categories')
  AND id = any (@idList)
ORDER BY old_value, source_company
```

And from there, the key change I would make is to pass your Id List as an array of integers or something that can be converted to an array of integers via .ToArray().

```
public DataTable GetDgvData(string selectQuery, string companyFilter, 
    string categoryFilter, int[] idFilter)
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("company", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
                companyFilter);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("category", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar,
                categoryFilter);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idList", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Array |
                NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, idFilter);
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Forgive my use of `AddWithValue` which I know is frowned upon in many circles...  Candidly, I love it and feel the arguments against it don't outweight its usefulness, especially with PostgreSQL.